# jQuery autocomplete remote source ampersand (&amp;) issue with php form

Tags: php, jquery, json, autocomplete, ampersand

I am using a jQuery autocomplete widget with a remote source. The widget is working fine except where the entry has an ampersand(&). The JSON that is being created by my php page is displaying the data correctly with the single & symbol. But the widget is interpreting it as html `&amp;`.

The html `&amp;` from the widget is then causing my php form to break. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried several things and nothing seems to work.

Here is the jQuery:

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            function log( message ) {
                $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
                $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
            }
        $( "#company" ).autocomplete({
        source: "autoComp/cds.php",
        minLength: 2,//search after two characters
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
            "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
            "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        }
        });
    });
  </script>
```

My php source page:

```
 <?php

$mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "casting2", 3306);

// If the connection didn't work out, there will be a connect_errno property on the $mysql object.  End
// the script with a fancy message.
if ($mysql->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysql->connect_error . ")";
}//connect to your database

$term = $_GET['term'];//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends
$theQuery = "SELECT company AS value, company AS id FROM cds WHERE company LIKE '%".$term."%'";

$result = $mysql->query($theQuery);

unset($row_set);


// Move to row number $i in the result set.
for ($i = 0; $i < $result->num_rows; $i++) {
    // Move to row number $i in the result set.
    $result->data_seek($i);

    // Get all the columns for the current row as an associative array -- we named it $aRow
    $aRow = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $aRow['value'] = htmlentities(stripslashes($aRow['value']));
    $aRow['id'] = htmlentities(stripslashes($aRow['id']));
    $row_set[] = $aRow; //build an array
}
    echo json_encode($row_set);//format the array into json data

$result->free();

?>
```

And here is an example of an entry from the array:

```
[{"value":"Bowling & Miscia Casting","id":"Bowling & Miscia Casting"}]
```

Thank you!

Comment: your `JSON` array is not what you provided it actually contains `&amp;` as you are encoding your values with `htmlentities` before adding it to your array

Comment: Wow, you are right. I had that there from a previous version. So simple. Thanks for catching it.